# Column 'HVQ_Vehicle.timestamp' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql

I have written a query to get the number of vehicles in a particular day of specific month. Here is my query,

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '1' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [1],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '2' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [2],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '3' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [3],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '4' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [4],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '5' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [5],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '6' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [6],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '7' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [7],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '8' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [8],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '9' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [9],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '10' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [10],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '11' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [11],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '12' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [12],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '13' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [13],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '14' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [14],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '15' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [15],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '16' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [16],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '17' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [17],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '18' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [18],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '19' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [19],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '20' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [20],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '21' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [21],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '22' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [22],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '23' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [23],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '24' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [24],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '25' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [25],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '26' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [26],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '27' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [27],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '28' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [28],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '29' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [29],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '30' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [30],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = '31' THEN (select count(Vehicle_Id)) ELSE '0' END AS [31]
FROM HVQ_Vehicle
where month(timestamp) = '08'
GROUP BY day(timestamp);
```

This gives result in two rows instead of single row. How to obtain in a single row. Here is the sample data.

```
Vehicle_Id          timestamp
8901361307130       2018-08-28 15:22:29.687
ME4JF39JGJT011230   2018-08-16 12:29:10.800
ME4JF39JGJT011231   2018-08-16 12:28:34.473
ME4JF39JGJT011232   2018-08-16 12:28:44.930
ME4JF39JGJT011233   2018-08-16 12:28:51.747
ME4JF39JGJT011234   2018-08-16 12:28:59.653
ME4JF39JGJT011235   2018-08-16 12:49:56.463
ME4JF39JGJT011236   2018-08-16 12:29:20.683
ME4JF39JGJT011237   2018-08-16 12:29:15.917
ME4JF39JGJT011239   2018-08-16 12:29:30.487
ME4JF39JGJT011240   2018-08-16 12:51:02.883
ME4JF39JGJT011241   2018-08-16 12:47:25.167
ME4JF39JGJT011242   2018-08-16 12:29:25.900
ME4JF39JGJT011243   2018-08-16 12:50:39.793
ME4JF39JGJT011244   2018-08-16 11:39:32.040
ME4JF39JGJT011245   2018-08-16 12:29:34.940
ME4JF39JGJT011246   2018-08-16 12:50:48.110
ME4JF39JGJT011248   2018-08-16 11:56:47.163
ME4JF39JGJT011250   2018-08-16 12:17:24.847
ME4JF39JGJT011252   2018-08-16 12:24:01.873
ME4JF39JGJT011253   2018-08-16 12:17:20.093
ME4JF39JGJT011254   2018-08-16 12:51:15.540
ME4JF39JGJT011255   2018-08-16 12:49:31.407
ME4JF39JGJT011257   2018-08-16 12:50:34.420
ME4JF39JGJT011260   2018-08-16 12:24:07.197
ME4JF39JGJT011262   2018-08-16 12:50:23.643
ME4JF39JGJT011263   2018-08-16 12:17:32.140
ME4JF39JGJT011264   2018-08-16 12:24:12.553
ME4JF39JGJT011265   2018-08-16 12:24:25.897
ME4JF39JGJT011266   2018-08-16 12:24:50.730
ME4JF39JGJT011267   2018-08-16 12:24:31.730
ME4JF39JGJT011271   2018-08-16 12:24:34.087
ME4JF39JGJT011275   2018-08-16 12:51:10.437
ME4JF39JGJT011288   2018-08-16 12:47:55.863
ME4JF39JGJT011293   2018-08-16 12:28:04.703
ME4JF39JGJT011294   2018-08-16 12:48:00.583
ME4JF39JGJT011316   2018-08-16 12:32:49.480
ME4JF39JGJT011324   2018-08-16 12:33:28.817
ME4JF39JGJT011327   2018-08-16 12:50:00.590
ME4JF39JGJT011330   2018-08-16 12:50:04.307
ME4JF39JGJT011336   2018-08-16 12:47:12.133
ME4JF39JGJT011340   2018-08-16 12:48:04.950
ME4JF39JGJT011347   2018-08-16 12:49:22.493
ME4JF39JGJT011353   2018-08-16 12:48:10.610
ME4JF39JGJT011367   2018-08-16 12:48:57.543
ME4JF39JGJT011370   2018-08-16 12:38:07.503
ME4JF39JGJT011373   2018-08-16 12:48:22.317
ME4JF39JGJT011394   2018-08-16 12:33:12.457
ME4JF39JGJT011400   2018-08-16 12:46:59.320
ME4JF39JGJT011405   2018-08-16 12:50:14.230
ME4JF39JGJT011406   2018-08-16 12:32:26.487
ME4JF39JGJT011407   2018-08-16 12:37:41.817
ME4JF39JGJT011408   2018-08-16 12:32:15.720
ME4JF39JGJT011409   2018-08-16 12:48:34.663
ME4JF39JGJT011410   2018-08-16 12:32:43.490
ME4JF39JGJT011411   2018-08-16 12:33:01.567
ME4JF39JGJT011412   2018-08-16 12:34:34.630
ME4JF39JGJT011413   2018-08-16 12:33:18.223
ME4JF39JGJT011415   2018-08-16 12:33:50.363
ME4JF39JGJT011416   2018-08-16 12:33:07.580
ME4JF39JGJT011417   2018-08-16 12:47:51.753
ME4JF39JGJT011418   2018-08-16 12:37:09.753
ME4JF39JGJT011419   2018-08-16 12:37:15.697
ME4JF39JGJT011423   2018-08-16 12:37:25.063
ME4JF39JGJT011425   2018-08-16 12:37:37.083
ME4JF39JGJT011426   2018-08-16 12:37:31.773
ME4JF39JGJT011427   2018-08-16 12:37:49.160
ME4JF39JGJT011428   2018-08-16 12:38:00.410
ME4JF39JGJT011429   2018-08-16 12:43:04.080
ME4JF39JGJT011430   2018-08-16 12:37:55.323
ME4JF39JGJT011431   2018-08-16 12:38:22.783
ME4JF39JGJT011432   2018-08-16 12:38:18.207
ME4JF39JGJT011433   2018-08-16 12:38:12.427
ME4JF39JGJT011434   2018-08-16 12:47:29.280
ME4JF39JGJT011435   2018-08-16 12:47:42.513
ME4JF39JGJT011436   2018-08-16 12:52:20.077
ME4JF39JGJT011437   2018-08-16 12:46:50.240
ME4JF39JGJT011443   2018-08-16 12:50:58.637
ME4JF39JGJT011444   2018-08-16 12:25:07.663
ME4JF39KGJT021354   2018-08-16 13:05:40.750
ME4JF39KGJT021362   2018-08-16 12:17:38.870
ME4JF39KGJT021364   2018-08-16 12:47:18.993
ME4JF39KGJT021372   2018-08-16 12:18:08.897
ME4JF39KGJT021377   2018-08-16 12:48:39.300
ME4JF39KGJT021384   2018-08-16 12:47:47.220
ME4JF39KGJT021386   2018-08-16 12:25:34.700
ME4JF39KGJT021388   2018-08-16 12:48:52.810
ME4JF39KGJT021397   2018-08-16 12:29:57.287
ME4JF39KGJT021398   2018-08-16 11:29:34.220
ME4JF39KGJT021412   2018-08-16 12:14:36.840
ME4JF39KGJT021420   2018-08-16 12:29:39.367
ME4JF39KGJT021423   2018-08-16 12:16:35.893
ME4JF39KGJT021424   2018-08-16 12:29:43.547
ME4JF39KGJT021425   2018-08-16 12:30:01.567
ME4JF39KGJT021426   2018-08-16 11:30:13.553
ME4JF39KGJT021427   2018-08-16 12:29:48.300
ME4JF39KGJT021428   2018-08-16 12:30:19.863
ME4JF39KGJT021429   2018-08-16 12:29:52.657
ME4JF39KGJT021430   2018-08-16 12:30:10.003
ME4JF39KGJT021431   2018-08-16 11:38:44.177
ME4JF39KGJT021432   2018-08-16 12:30:33.460
ME4JF39KGJT021434   2018-08-16 12:30:26.050
ME4JF39KGJT021435   2018-08-16 12:15:58.357
ME4JF39KGJT021438   2018-08-16 12:26:03.990
ME4JF39KGJT021439   2018-08-16 12:13:01.380
ME4JF39KGJT021440   2018-08-16 12:03:35.790
ME4JF39KGJT021441   2018-08-16 12:22:33.293
ME4JF39KGJT021442   2018-08-16 11:32:37.747
ME4JF39KGJT021443   2018-08-16 11:32:15.900
ME4JF39KGJT021444   2018-08-16 11:35:11.967
ME4JF39KGJT021446   2018-08-16 11:32:52.153
ME4JF39KGJT021447   2018-08-16 11:30:48.090
ME4JF39KGJT021449   2018-08-16 12:20:59.583
ME4JF39KGJT021452   2018-08-16 11:29:48.190
ME4JF39KGJT021453   2018-08-16 11:29:41.440
ME4JF39KGJT021454   2018-08-16 12:23:17.540
ME4JF39KGJT021455   2018-08-16 12:18:21.760
ME4JF39KGJT021461   2018-08-16 12:18:00.293
ME4JF39KGJT021462   2018-08-16 12:18:27.483
ME4JF39KGJT021463   2018-08-16 12:17:45.117
ME4JF39KGJT021466   2018-08-16 12:18:15.113
ME4JF39KGJT021467   2018-08-16 12:25:48.760
ME4JF39KGJT021469   2018-08-16 12:19:27.310
ME4JF39KGJT021471   2018-08-16 12:18:32.743
ME4JF39KGJT021473   2018-08-16 12:19:19.240
ME4JF39KGJT021474   2018-08-16 12:19:06.933
ME4JF39KGJT021475   2018-08-16 12:23:28.230
ME4JF39KGJT021478   2018-08-16 12:19:34.240
ME4JF39KGJT021479   2018-08-16 12:26:38.173
ME4JF39KGJT021481   2018-08-16 12:19:50.300
ME4JF39KGJT021482   2018-08-16 12:21:28.387
ME4JF39KGJT021483   2018-08-16 12:21:05.973
ME4JF39KGJT021484   2018-08-16 12:25:43.087
ME4JF39KGJT021486   2018-08-16 11:29:14.470
ME4JF39KGJT021487   2018-08-16 12:22:09.257
ME4JF39KGJT021488   2018-08-16 12:23:56.220
ME4JF39KGJT021490   2018-08-16 12:23:49.507
ME4JF39KGJT021491   2018-08-16 12:25:27.283
ME4JF39KGJT021492   2018-08-16 12:25:58.003
ME4JF39KGJT021494   2018-08-16 12:26:22.797
ME4JF39KGJT021497   2018-08-16 12:52:16.193
ME4JF39KGJT021498   2018-08-16 12:27:33.660
ME4JF39KGJT021499   2018-08-16 13:01:57.043
ME4JF39KGJT021501   2018-08-16 12:27:39.693
ME4JF39KGJT021504   2018-08-16 12:53:01.293
ME4JF39KGJT021509   2018-08-16 12:51:56.460
ME4JF39KGJT021510   2018-08-16 12:52:11.157
ME4JF39KGJT021511   2018-08-16 12:52:01.523
ME4JF39KGJT021513   2018-08-16 12:27:44.803
ME4JF39KGJT021516   2018-08-16 12:26:08.757
ME4JF39KGJT021517   2018-08-16 12:26:42.980
ME4JF39KGJT021518   2018-08-16 12:26:28.160
ME4JF39KGJT021532   2018-08-16 13:02:29.980
ME4JF39KGJT021538   2018-08-16 13:00:47.727
ME4JF39KGJT021542   2018-08-16 12:46:38.143
ME4JF39KGJT021550   2018-08-16 11:21:27.917
ME4JF39KGJT021557   2018-08-16 12:57:43.287
ME4JF39KGJT021558   2018-08-16 12:24:56.433
ME4JF39KGJT021560   2018-08-16 12:58:39.753
ME4JF39KGJT021561   2018-08-16 12:52:51.077
ME4JF39KGJT021562   2018-08-16 12:57:28.667
ME4JF39KGJT021564   2018-08-16 12:56:58.510
ME4JF39KGJT021565   2018-08-16 12:58:04.210
ME4JF39KGJT021566   2018-08-16 12:53:29.837
ME4JF39KGJT021567   2018-08-16 12:52:32.150
ME4JF39KGJT021568   2018-08-16 12:53:24.850
ME4JF39KGJT021569   2018-08-16 12:52:27.643
ME4JF39KGJT021570   2018-08-16 12:57:20.223
ME4JF39KGJT021571   2018-08-16 12:53:45.243
ME4JF39KGJT021572   2018-08-16 12:25:21.203
ME4JF39KGJT021573   2018-08-16 12:25:01.650
ME4JF39KGJT021575   2018-08-16 12:53:20.980
ME4JF39KGJT021577   2018-08-16 12:52:35.453
ME4JF39KGJT021578   2018-08-16 13:02:25.413
ME4JF39KGJT021580   2018-08-16 12:53:11.620
ME4JF39KGJT021581   2018-08-16 12:45:48.337
ME4JF39KGJT021582   2018-08-16 13:05:21.917
ME4JF39KGJT021584   2018-08-16 13:00:41.867
ME4JF39KGJT021585   2018-08-16 12:53:34.590
ME4JF39KGJT021586   2018-08-16 12:53:40.650
ME4JF39KGJT021587   2018-08-16 13:00:54.730
ME4JF39KGJT021588   2018-08-16 13:00:21.457
ME4JF39KGJT021589   2018-08-16 13:00:28.360
ME4JF39KGJT021591   2018-08-16 13:01:06.947
ME4JF39KGJT021592   2018-08-16 12:51:41.110
ME4JF39KGJT021593   2018-08-16 13:02:31.723
ME4JF39KGJT021594   2018-08-16 13:02:34.067
ME4JF39KGJT021595   2018-08-16 13:01:11.773
ME4JF39KGJT021597   2018-08-16 13:02:38.293
ME4JF39KGJT021598   2018-08-16 13:02:36.473
ME4JF39KGJT021599   2018-08-16 13:02:27.450
ME4JF39KGJT021600   2018-08-16 13:04:37.527
ME4JF39KGJT021601   2018-08-16 13:02:42.420
ME4JF39KGJT021602   2018-08-16 13:02:40.047
ME4JF39KGJT021603   2018-08-16 13:05:20.157
ME4JF39KGJT021604   2018-08-16 13:05:09.630
ME4JF39KGJT021605   2018-08-16 13:05:17.503
ME4JF39KGJT021606   2018-08-16 13:05:11.843
ME4JF39KGJT021607   2018-08-16 13:05:14.000
ME4JF39KGJT021608   2018-08-16 12:46:42.440
ME4JF39KGJT021609   2018-08-16 13:05:25.323
ME4JF39KGJT021610   2018-08-16 13:05:37.200
ME4JF39KGJT021612   2018-08-16 13:05:29.637
ME4JF39KGJT021613   2018-08-16 13:05:26.920
ME4JF39KGJT021614   2018-08-16 13:05:31.503
ME4JF39KGJT021615   2018-08-16 13:05:33.310
ME4JF39KGJT021616   2018-08-16 13:05:39.063
ME4JF39KGJT021617   2018-08-16 13:02:22.700
ME4JF39KGJT021618   2018-08-16 12:46:00.277
ME4JF39KGJT021619   2018-08-16 12:46:46.460
ME4JF39KGJT021620   2018-08-16 13:01:59.257
ME4JF39KGJT021622   2018-08-16 13:05:44.497
ME4JF39KGJT021623   2018-08-16 13:16:06.093
ME4JF39KGJT021624   2018-08-16 13:09:34.527
ME4JF39KGJT021625   2018-08-16 13:16:19.583
ME4JF39KGJT021626   2018-08-16 13:09:02.427
ME4JF39KGJT021628   2018-08-16 12:27:12.850
ME4JF39KGJT021629   2018-08-16 13:13:53.940
ME4JF39KGJT021630   2018-08-16 13:13:40.230
ME4JF39KGJT021631   2018-08-16 14:15:12.827
ME4JF39KGJT021632   2018-08-16 12:26:49.637
ME4JF39KGJT021633   2018-08-16 12:26:59.393
ME4JF39KGJT021634   2018-08-16 12:27:04.823
ME4JF39KGJT021635   2018-08-16 12:26:54.150
ME4JF39KGJT021637   2018-08-16 12:27:22.893
ME4JF39KGJT021639   2018-08-16 14:16:09.507
ME4JF39KGJT021642   2018-08-16 12:45:58.010
ME4JF39KGJT021647   2018-08-16 12:46:04.480
ME4JF39LGJT004941   2018-08-16 13:05:35.230
ME4JF39LGJT004944   2018-08-16 12:48:30.933
ME4JF39LGJT004948   2018-08-16 12:51:26.400
ME4JF39LGJT004955   2018-08-16 12:49:16.207
ME4JF39LGJT004960   2018-08-16 12:51:19.993
ME4JF39LGJT004961   2018-08-16 12:40:53.050
ME4JF39LGJT004962   2018-08-16 12:42:20.123
ME4JF39LGJT004963   2018-08-16 12:41:38.940
ME4JF39LGJT004964   2018-08-16 12:48:26.393
ME4JF39LGJT004965   2018-08-16 12:45:40.180
ME4JF39LGJT004971   2018-08-16 12:42:25.570
ME4JF39LGJT004973   2018-08-16 12:42:00.537
ME4JF39LGJT004975   2018-08-16 12:46:54.520
ME4JF39LGJT004976   2018-08-16 12:41:07.600
ME4JF39LGJT004977   2018-08-16 12:42:53.910
ME4JF39LGJT004978   2018-08-16 12:41:51.473
ME4JF39LGJT004979   2018-08-16 12:42:48.970
ME4JF39LGJT004980   2018-08-16 12:41:26.520
ME4JF39LGJT004981   2018-08-16 12:42:59.330
ME4JF39LGJT004982   2018-08-16 12:41:46.800
ME4JF39LGJT004983   2018-08-16 12:45:04.287
ME4JF39LGJT004984   2018-08-16 12:42:14.223
ME4JF39LGJT004985   2018-08-16 12:28:11.770
ME4JF39LGJT004986   2018-08-16 12:51:31.970
ME4JF39LGJT004987   2018-08-16 12:47:36.343
ME4JF39LGJT004988   2018-08-16 12:42:33.300
ME4JF39LGJT004989   2018-08-16 12:42:06.740
ME4JF39LGJT004990   2018-08-16 12:43:24.860
ME4JF39LGJT004994   2018-08-16 12:42:43.567
ME4JF39LGJT004995   2018-08-16 12:43:12.427
ME4JF39LGJT004996   2018-08-16 12:45:36.163
ME4JF39LGJT004997   2018-08-16 12:46:08.607
ME4JF39LGJT004998   2018-08-16 12:39:02.707
ME4JF39LGJT004999   2018-08-16 12:43:18.433
ME4JF39LGJT005000   2018-08-16 12:48:43.570
ME4JF39LGJT005001   2018-08-16 12:45:20.320
ME4JF39LGJT005003   2018-08-16 12:27:51.207
ME4JF39LGJT005004   2018-08-16 12:45:24.617
ME4JF39LGJT005007   2018-08-16 12:39:13.550
ME4JF39LGJT005009   2018-08-16 12:27:56.553
ME4JF39LGJT005011   2018-08-16 12:38:56.800
ME4JF39LGJT005012   2018-08-16 12:50:53.890
ME4JF39LGJT005013   2018-08-16 12:38:27.473
ME4JF39LGJT005014   2018-08-16 12:38:33.690
ME4JF39LGJT005015   2018-08-16 12:47:04.227
ME4JF39LGJT005016   2018-08-16 12:39:07.973
ME4JF39LGJT005017   2018-08-16 12:39:32.520
ME4JF39LGJT005018   2018-08-16 12:40:06.283
ME4JF39LGJT005019   2018-08-16 12:39:44.737
ME4JF39LGJT005020   2018-08-16 12:39:18.817
ME4JF50AGJT341071   2018-08-16 11:33:59.723
ME4JF50AGJT344724   2018-08-16 13:30:00.280
ME4JF50AGJT344816   2018-08-16 13:28:37.483
ME4JF50AGJT344818   2018-08-16 13:29:28.207
ME4JF50AGJT344824   2018-08-16 13:28:08.810
ME4JF50AGJT344826   2018-08-16 13:29:41.537
ME4JF50AGJT344830   2018-08-16 13:27:57.753
ME4JF50AGJT344873   2018-08-16 13:28:50.010
ME4JF50AGJT344882   2018-08-16 13:27:32.163
ME4JF50AGJT344886   2018-08-16 13:27:43.630
ME4JF50BGJT157862   2018-08-16 13:20:02.167
ME4JF50BGJT157891   2018-08-16 13:22:06.110
ME4JF50BGJT157909   2018-08-16 13:18:54.710
ME4JF50BGJT157910   2018-08-16 13:26:59.917
ME4JF50BGJT157934   2018-08-16 13:23:02.110
ME4JF50BGJT157962   2018-08-16 13:22:22.743
ME4JF50BGJT157965   2018-08-16 13:27:18.143
ME4JF50BGJT157997   2018-08-16 13:22:47.020
ME4JF50BGJT158010   2018-08-16 13:27:08.810
ME4JF50BGJT158014   2018-08-16 13:21:02.943
ME4JF50BGJT158018   2018-08-16 13:20:52.230
ME4JF50BGJT158119   2018-08-16 12:24:18.903
ME4JF50BGJT158138   2018-08-16 12:45:29.070
P1022734-004    2018-08-28 15:23:44.017
```

I need to print on date 16 count is 300, on 28 count is 2 and rest 1,2...31 it should display 0.

Comment: The error message is clear, but it can't easily be correlated to your actual code, because your code is not even remotely readable.  Please take a few minutes and format your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below - you've wrote the syntax wrongly - it should be `count(case when your condition then Vehicle_Id  END)`

```
SELECT  count(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 1 THEN Vehicle_Id  END) AS [1],
               count(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 2 THEN Vehicle_Id END) AS [2],
               count(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 3 THEN Vehicle_Id END) AS [3],
               .......
               FROM HVQ_Vehicle where month(timestamp) = 8;
```

Comment: DATEPART() and MONTH() return INT

Comment: Thanks, But it is giving the count of vehicle ids for whole month. Actually the requirement is to get the count of vehicle ids per day in a particular month.

Comment: Sorry sir, It,s giving the count of vehicle ids for whole month  without group by clause also. I need to count vehicle ids for particular day, if there are no vehicle then answer should be 0. Please help me out.

Comment: can you please share some of your sample data in question - it would be great to help u @PavitraSharma

Comment: fa06's query works fine - see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=06958b614d152e95a5978052669ad8e0

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any problems implementing fa06's suggestion, though I swapped the COUNT for SUM and the use of MONTH/DAY with DATEPART. These are relatively non-ops though:

Here is setup:

```
CREATE TABLE hvq_vehicle
    ([Vehicle_Id] varchar(17), [timestamp] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO hvq_vehicle
    ([Vehicle_Id], [timestamp])
VALUES
    ('8901361307130', '2018-08-28 15:22:29'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011230', '2018-08-16 12:29:10'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011231', '2018-08-16 12:28:34'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011232', '2018-08-16 12:28:44'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011233', '2018-08-16 12:28:51'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011234', '2018-08-16 12:28:59'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011235', '2018-08-16 12:49:56'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011236', '2018-08-16 12:29:20'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011237', '2018-08-16 12:29:15'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011239', '2018-08-16 12:29:30'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011240', '2018-08-16 12:51:02'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011241', '2018-08-16 12:47:25'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011242', '2018-08-16 12:29:25'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011243', '2018-08-16 12:50:39'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011244', '2018-08-16 11:39:32'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011245', '2018-08-16 12:29:34'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011246', '2018-08-16 12:50:48'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011248', '2018-08-16 11:56:47'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011250', '2018-08-16 12:17:24'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011252', '2018-08-16 12:24:01'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011253', '2018-08-16 12:17:20'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011254', '2018-08-16 12:51:15'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011255', '2018-08-16 12:49:31'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011257', '2018-08-16 12:50:34'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011260', '2018-08-16 12:24:07'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011262', '2018-08-16 12:50:23'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011263', '2018-08-16 12:17:32'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011264', '2018-08-16 12:24:12'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011265', '2018-08-16 12:24:25'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011266', '2018-08-16 12:24:50'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011267', '2018-08-16 12:24:31'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011271', '2018-08-16 12:24:34'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011275', '2018-08-16 12:51:10'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011288', '2018-08-16 12:47:55'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011293', '2018-08-16 12:28:04'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011294', '2018-08-16 12:48:00'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011316', '2018-08-16 12:32:49'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011324', '2018-08-16 12:33:28'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011327', '2018-08-16 12:50:00'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011330', '2018-08-16 12:50:04'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011336', '2018-08-16 12:47:12'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011340', '2018-08-16 12:48:04'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011347', '2018-08-16 12:49:22'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011353', '2018-08-16 12:48:10'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011367', '2018-08-16 12:48:57'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011370', '2018-08-16 12:38:07'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011373', '2018-08-16 12:48:22'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011394', '2018-08-16 12:33:12'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011400', '2018-08-16 12:46:59'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011405', '2018-08-16 12:50:14'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011406', '2018-08-16 12:32:26'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011407', '2018-08-16 12:37:41'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011408', '2018-08-16 12:32:15'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011409', '2018-08-16 12:48:34'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011410', '2018-08-16 12:32:43'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011411', '2018-08-16 12:33:01'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011412', '2018-08-16 12:34:34'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011413', '2018-08-16 12:33:18'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011415', '2018-08-16 12:33:50'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011416', '2018-08-16 12:33:07'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011417', '2018-08-16 12:47:51'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011418', '2018-08-16 12:37:09'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011419', '2018-08-16 12:37:15'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011423', '2018-08-16 12:37:25'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011425', '2018-08-16 12:37:37'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011426', '2018-08-16 12:37:31'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011427', '2018-08-16 12:37:49'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011428', '2018-08-16 12:38:00'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011429', '2018-08-16 12:43:04'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011430', '2018-08-16 12:37:55'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011431', '2018-08-16 12:38:22'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011432', '2018-08-16 12:38:18'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011433', '2018-08-16 12:38:12'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011434', '2018-08-16 12:47:29'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011435', '2018-08-16 12:47:42'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011436', '2018-08-16 12:52:20'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011437', '2018-08-16 12:46:50'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011443', '2018-08-16 12:50:58'),
    ('ME4JF39JGJT011444', '2018-08-16 12:25:07'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021354', '2018-08-16 13:05:40'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021362', '2018-08-16 12:17:38'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021364', '2018-08-16 12:47:18'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021372', '2018-08-16 12:18:08'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021377', '2018-08-16 12:48:39'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021384', '2018-08-16 12:47:47'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021386', '2018-08-16 12:25:34'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021388', '2018-08-16 12:48:52'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021397', '2018-08-16 12:29:57'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021398', '2018-08-16 11:29:34'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021412', '2018-08-16 12:14:36'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021420', '2018-08-16 12:29:39'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021423', '2018-08-16 12:16:35'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021424', '2018-08-16 12:29:43'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021425', '2018-08-16 12:30:01'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021426', '2018-08-16 11:30:13'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021427', '2018-08-16 12:29:48'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021428', '2018-08-16 12:30:19'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021429', '2018-08-16 12:29:52'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021430', '2018-08-16 12:30:10'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021431', '2018-08-16 11:38:44'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021432', '2018-08-16 12:30:33'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021434', '2018-08-16 12:30:26'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021435', '2018-08-16 12:15:58'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021438', '2018-08-16 12:26:03'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021439', '2018-08-16 12:13:01'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021440', '2018-08-16 12:03:35'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021441', '2018-08-16 12:22:33'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021442', '2018-08-16 11:32:37'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021443', '2018-08-16 11:32:15'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021444', '2018-08-16 11:35:11'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021446', '2018-08-16 11:32:52'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021447', '2018-08-16 11:30:48'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021449', '2018-08-16 12:20:59'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021452', '2018-08-16 11:29:48'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021453', '2018-08-16 11:29:41'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021454', '2018-08-16 12:23:17'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021455', '2018-08-16 12:18:21'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021461', '2018-08-16 12:18:00'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021462', '2018-08-16 12:18:27'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021463', '2018-08-16 12:17:45'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021466', '2018-08-16 12:18:15'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021467', '2018-08-16 12:25:48'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021469', '2018-08-16 12:19:27'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021471', '2018-08-16 12:18:32'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021473', '2018-08-16 12:19:19'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021474', '2018-08-16 12:19:06'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021475', '2018-08-16 12:23:28'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021478', '2018-08-16 12:19:34'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021479', '2018-08-16 12:26:38'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021481', '2018-08-16 12:19:50'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021482', '2018-08-16 12:21:28'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021483', '2018-08-16 12:21:05'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021484', '2018-08-16 12:25:43'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021486', '2018-08-16 11:29:14'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021487', '2018-08-16 12:22:09'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021488', '2018-08-16 12:23:56'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021490', '2018-08-16 12:23:49'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021491', '2018-08-16 12:25:27'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021492', '2018-08-16 12:25:58'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021494', '2018-08-16 12:26:22'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021497', '2018-08-16 12:52:16'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021498', '2018-08-16 12:27:33'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021499', '2018-08-16 13:01:57'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021501', '2018-08-16 12:27:39'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021504', '2018-08-16 12:53:01'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021509', '2018-08-16 12:51:56'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021510', '2018-08-16 12:52:11'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021511', '2018-08-16 12:52:01'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021513', '2018-08-16 12:27:44'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021516', '2018-08-16 12:26:08'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021517', '2018-08-16 12:26:42'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021518', '2018-08-16 12:26:28'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021532', '2018-08-16 13:02:29'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021538', '2018-08-16 13:00:47'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021542', '2018-08-16 12:46:38'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021550', '2018-08-16 11:21:27'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021557', '2018-08-16 12:57:43'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021558', '2018-08-16 12:24:56'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021560', '2018-08-16 12:58:39'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021561', '2018-08-16 12:52:51'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021562', '2018-08-16 12:57:28'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021564', '2018-08-16 12:56:58'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021565', '2018-08-16 12:58:04'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021566', '2018-08-16 12:53:29'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021567', '2018-08-16 12:52:32'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021568', '2018-08-16 12:53:24'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021569', '2018-08-16 12:52:27'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021570', '2018-08-16 12:57:20'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021571', '2018-08-16 12:53:45'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021572', '2018-08-16 12:25:21'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021573', '2018-08-16 12:25:01'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021575', '2018-08-16 12:53:20'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021577', '2018-08-16 12:52:35'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021578', '2018-08-16 13:02:25'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021580', '2018-08-16 12:53:11'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021581', '2018-08-16 12:45:48'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021582', '2018-08-16 13:05:21'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021584', '2018-08-16 13:00:41'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021585', '2018-08-16 12:53:34'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021586', '2018-08-16 12:53:40'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021587', '2018-08-16 13:00:54'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021588', '2018-08-16 13:00:21'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021589', '2018-08-16 13:00:28'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021591', '2018-08-16 13:01:06'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021592', '2018-08-16 12:51:41'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021593', '2018-08-16 13:02:31'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021594', '2018-08-16 13:02:34'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021595', '2018-08-16 13:01:11'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021597', '2018-08-16 13:02:38'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021598', '2018-08-16 13:02:36'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021599', '2018-08-16 13:02:27'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021600', '2018-08-16 13:04:37'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021601', '2018-08-16 13:02:42'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021602', '2018-08-16 13:02:40'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021603', '2018-08-16 13:05:20'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021604', '2018-08-16 13:05:09'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021605', '2018-08-16 13:05:17'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021606', '2018-08-16 13:05:11'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021607', '2018-08-16 13:05:14'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021608', '2018-08-16 12:46:42'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021609', '2018-08-16 13:05:25'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021610', '2018-08-16 13:05:37'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021612', '2018-08-16 13:05:29'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021613', '2018-08-16 13:05:26'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021614', '2018-08-16 13:05:31'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021615', '2018-08-16 13:05:33'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021616', '2018-08-16 13:05:39'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021617', '2018-08-16 13:02:22'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021618', '2018-08-16 12:46:00'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021619', '2018-08-16 12:46:46'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021620', '2018-08-16 13:01:59'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021622', '2018-08-16 13:05:44'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021623', '2018-08-16 13:16:06'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021624', '2018-08-16 13:09:34'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021625', '2018-08-16 13:16:19'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021626', '2018-08-16 13:09:02'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021628', '2018-08-16 12:27:12'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021629', '2018-08-16 13:13:53'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021630', '2018-08-16 13:13:40'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021631', '2018-08-16 14:15:12'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021632', '2018-08-16 12:26:49'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021633', '2018-08-16 12:26:59'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021634', '2018-08-16 12:27:04'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021635', '2018-08-16 12:26:54'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021637', '2018-08-16 12:27:22'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021639', '2018-08-16 14:16:09'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021642', '2018-08-16 12:45:58'),
    ('ME4JF39KGJT021647', '2018-08-16 12:46:04'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004941', '2018-08-16 13:05:35'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004944', '2018-08-16 12:48:30'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004948', '2018-08-16 12:51:26'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004955', '2018-08-16 12:49:16'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004960', '2018-08-16 12:51:19'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004961', '2018-08-16 12:40:53'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004962', '2018-08-16 12:42:20'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004963', '2018-08-16 12:41:38'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004964', '2018-08-16 12:48:26'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004965', '2018-08-16 12:45:40'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004971', '2018-08-16 12:42:25'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004973', '2018-08-16 12:42:00'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004975', '2018-08-16 12:46:54'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004976', '2018-08-16 12:41:07'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004977', '2018-08-16 12:42:53'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004978', '2018-08-16 12:41:51'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004979', '2018-08-16 12:42:48'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004980', '2018-08-16 12:41:26'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004981', '2018-08-16 12:42:59'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004982', '2018-08-16 12:41:46'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004983', '2018-08-16 12:45:04'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004984', '2018-08-16 12:42:14'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004985', '2018-08-16 12:28:11'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004986', '2018-08-16 12:51:31'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004987', '2018-08-16 12:47:36'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004988', '2018-08-16 12:42:33'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004989', '2018-08-16 12:42:06'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004990', '2018-08-16 12:43:24'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004994', '2018-08-16 12:42:43'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004995', '2018-08-16 12:43:12'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004996', '2018-08-16 12:45:36'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004997', '2018-08-16 12:46:08'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004998', '2018-08-16 12:39:02'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT004999', '2018-08-16 12:43:18'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT005000', '2018-08-16 12:48:43'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT005001', '2018-08-16 12:45:20'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT005003', '2018-08-16 12:27:51'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT005004', '2018-08-16 12:45:24'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT005007', '2018-08-16 12:39:13'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT005009', '2018-08-16 12:27:56'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT005011', '2018-08-16 12:38:56'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT005012', '2018-08-16 12:50:53'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT005013', '2018-08-16 12:38:27'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT005014', '2018-08-16 12:38:33'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT005015', '2018-08-16 12:47:04'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT005016', '2018-08-16 12:39:07'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT005017', '2018-08-16 12:39:32'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT005018', '2018-08-16 12:40:06'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT005019', '2018-08-16 12:39:44'),
    ('ME4JF39LGJT005020', '2018-08-16 12:39:18'),
    ('ME4JF50AGJT341071', '2018-08-16 11:33:59'),
    ('ME4JF50AGJT344724', '2018-08-16 13:30:00'),
    ('ME4JF50AGJT344816', '2018-08-16 13:28:37'),
    ('ME4JF50AGJT344818', '2018-08-16 13:29:28'),
    ('ME4JF50AGJT344824', '2018-08-16 13:28:08'),
    ('ME4JF50AGJT344826', '2018-08-16 13:29:41'),
    ('ME4JF50AGJT344830', '2018-08-16 13:27:57'),
    ('ME4JF50AGJT344873', '2018-08-16 13:28:50'),
    ('ME4JF50AGJT344882', '2018-08-16 13:27:32'),
    ('ME4JF50AGJT344886', '2018-08-16 13:27:43'),
    ('ME4JF50BGJT157862', '2018-08-16 13:20:02'),
    ('ME4JF50BGJT157891', '2018-08-16 13:22:06'),
    ('ME4JF50BGJT157909', '2018-08-16 13:18:54'),
    ('ME4JF50BGJT157910', '2018-08-16 13:26:59'),
    ('ME4JF50BGJT157934', '2018-08-16 13:23:02'),
    ('ME4JF50BGJT157962', '2018-08-16 13:22:22'),
    ('ME4JF50BGJT157965', '2018-08-16 13:27:18'),
    ('ME4JF50BGJT157997', '2018-08-16 13:22:47'),
    ('ME4JF50BGJT158010', '2018-08-16 13:27:08'),
    ('ME4JF50BGJT158014', '2018-08-16 13:21:02'),
    ('ME4JF50BGJT158018', '2018-08-16 13:20:52'),
    ('ME4JF50BGJT158119', '2018-08-16 12:24:18'),
    ('ME4JF50BGJT158138', '2018-08-16 12:45:29'),
    ('P1022734-004', '2018-08-28 15:23:44')
;
```

The query doing the work:

```
SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [1],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [3],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [4],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [5],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [6],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [7],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [8],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [9],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [10],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [11],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [12],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [13],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [14],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [15],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [16],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [17],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [18],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [19],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [20],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 21 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [21],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [22],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [23],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [24],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [25],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 26 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [26],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 27 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [27],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 28 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [28],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 29 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [29],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [30],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, timestamp) = 31 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [31]
FROM HVQ_Vehicle
WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, timestamp) = 8;
```

And the result requested:

[image]